# Перевести программу с Паскаля на С++

Tags: pascal, c++

```
program  laboratorna1;
uses crt;
type ar=array[0..10, 1..2] of real;
var j, n, i: integer;
    a: ar;
    s: real;
function taras(n: integer; a: ar): real;
var i: integer;
    s: real;
begin
    s := 0;
    a[0,1] := a[n,1];
    a[0,2] := a[n,2];

    for i:=0 to n-1 do
        s := s + (a[i, 1] + a[i+1, 1]) * (a[i, 2] - a[i+1, 2]);
    taras := abs(s) / 2;
end;

begin
    clrscr;
    writeln('vvedit n');
    readln(n);
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
        for j := 1 to 2 do
        begin
           write('a[', i, ',', j, ']');
            read(a[i, j]);
        end;
    end;

    s := taras(n, a);
    write('s=', s:5:2);
    readkey;
end.
```

я пробовал но не выходит

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10] [2];{
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
for (int j=1;j<2;j++) 
double taras(int n;double**a){
 int i;
 double s=0;
 a[0][1]=a[n][1];
 a[0][2]=a[n][2]; 
 for(i=0;i<n;I++) s=s+(a[i][1]+a[i+1][1])*(a[i][2]-a[i+1][2]);
 return fabs(s)/2;
}
{
int j,n,i
double a[11,2],s;
printf("vvedit n");scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<n-1,i++)
for(j=1;j<2;j++){
 printf("a[%d][%d] = ",i,j);
 scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
}

s=taras(n,&a);
printf("s=%5.2f"',s);
getchar();
}
```

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что бюро переводов закрыто на переучёт.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double taras(int n; double**a){
    int i;
    double s=0;
    a[0][1]=a[n][1];
    a[0][2]=a[n][2]; 
    for(i=0;i<n;I++) s=s+(a[i][1]+a[i+1][1])*(a[i][2]-a[i+1][2]);
    return fabs(s)/2;
}
int main()
{
    int a[10] [2];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) 
        for (int j=1;j<2;j++) 
        {
            int j,n,i
            double a[11,2],s;
            printf("vvedit n");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(i=1;i<n-1,i++)
                for(j=1;j<2;j++){
                    printf("a[%d][%d] = ",i,j);
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
                }

            s=taras(n,&a);
            printf("s=%5.2f"',s);
            getchar();
        }
}
```